# What is a malformed token?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

I am reading Programming Language Pragmatics by Michael Scott. He says that on a first pass, a compiler will break a program into a series of tokens. He says that it will check for malformed tokens, like 123abc or $@foo (in C).

What is a malformed token? A variable that does not meet the rules of variable-naming? An operator that does not exist (ex. "<-")?

Is this analogous to a misspelled word?

Comment: That is any token that is rejected by a certain (languge-specific) finite state automaton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic syntactic units in any *textual* programming language are tokens, which are, if you wish, the words in the programming language. The compiler parses these tokens to build sentences and so forth.

A malformed token is a string of characters that is not a valid word for the programming language.

It is not a variable that doesn't match the naming rules – not all tokens are variables. It is not an operator that is unknown – sometimes operators can be defined by the programmer. It is one of the smallest pieces of syntax that will never correspond to something sensible.

Comment: Aren't the basic syntactic units called lexemes and tokens are classes of lexemes?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.